# Multiple Alignments in flalign

Tags: align, amsmath

I would like to align the following formula:

```
\begin{flalign*} 
& 100000 & + 1 & = 100001 &\\
& 1      & + 1 & = 2 &\\
\end{flalign*}
```

I would like the alignment to be just like the text file. So everything left aligned, then some space after `1` in the second row to align the `+` right underneath the `+` in the first row. However, what I get is:

[image]

How can I remove all this unnecessary space between `100000`, `1`, and `+`.

Comment: Is this only one equation which you like to have aligned to left border of text?

Comment: It's two equations (things with `=`) that should be aligned to the left border of the text.

Comment: Must the `=`   signs be aligned?

Answer (score 5):

Here are 4 different possibilities for a left alignment with `\flalign*`, and two with the `\fleqn` environment of `nccmath` , which allows for a `\displayindent`:

```
    \documentclass{article}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}%
 \usepackage{mathtools, nccmath}
    \usepackage{array}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\setstackEOL{\\}

    \begin{document}

\begin{flalign*}
\intertext{with \texttt{flalign*}: }
 100000 + 1 & = 100001 &\\
  1 + 1 & = 2 &
\end{flalign*}

\begin{flalign*}
 &    100000 + 1  = 100001 &   \\
 &  1 + 1  = 2
\end{flalign*}


\begin{flalign*}
        100000   & + 1  = 100001 &    \\
   \mathrlap{1}  \phantom{000000}  & + 1  = 2
\end{flalign*}

\begin{flalign*}
\begin{gathered}
    100000 + 1  = 100001   \\
  1 + 1  = 2
 \end{gathered}
  & &
\end{flalign*}

\begin{fleqn}[2em]
\begin{align*}
\intertext{with \texttt{fleqn}: }
 100000 + 1 & = 100001  \\
  1 + 1 & = 2
\end{align*}
\end{fleqn}

\begin{fleqn}[2em]
\begin{gather*}
     100000 + 1  = 100001   \\
  1 + 1  = 2
\end{gather*}
\end{fleqn}

    \end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

In my opinion, it doesn't make sense to left align only some equations, so first I provide a version with `fleqn`

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}
\usepackage{lipsum} % just for the example

\setlength{\mathindent}{0pt} % don't do this, please!

\begin{document}

\lipsum*[2]
\begin{alignat*}{3}
&10000 &&+1  &&= 10001 \\
&1     &&+10 &&= 11
\end{alignat*}
\lipsum[3]

\end{document}
```

However, setting `\mathindent` to zero is not something I'd recommend.

If you don't want to use `fleqn` and just want to left align those equations, you can use `alignedat` inside `flalign`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{lipsum} % just for the example

\begin{document}

\lipsum*[2]
\begin{flalign*}
\begin{alignedat}{3}
&10000 &&+1  &&= 10001 \\
&1     &&+10 &&= 11
\end{alignedat}
&&
\end{flalign*}
\lipsum[3]

\end{document}
```

The output is the same in both cases (other equations without `flalign` would have different placement, of course).

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You could use a TABstack (depending on whether the OP's MWE describes the full requirement or not).  The gap is defined with `\setstackaligngap{<length>}` (default 1em).

NOTE: `tabstackengine` default alignments require `=&` rather than `&=`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tabstackengine}
\stackMath
\begin{document}
\noindent\alignLongstack{
& 100000 & + 1 = & 100001\\
& 1      & + 1 = & 2\\
}

\setstackaligngap{3em}
\noindent\alignLongstack{
& 100000 & + 1 = & 100001\\
& 1      & + 1 = & 2\\
}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! The code works in free floating text, but I'm trying to put it into a float and it breaks with the error: https://gist.github.com/konne88/5e9d25c2e3818c31cf6b15d9dd8d4a27

Comment: @KonstantinWeitz A more robust version of `tabstackengine` is in the works (that copes with the redefinition of `\\ `), but in the meantime, you can overcome this problem by choosing a different end-of-line character for the stack: `\setstackEOL{\cr}
\alignLongstack{
& 100000 & + 1 = & 100001\cr
& 1      & + 1 = & 2\cr
}`.  Alternately, you can `\let\sveol\\ ` in the preamble, and then restore that inside the environment: `\let\\\sveol
\alignLongstack{
& 100000 & + 1 = & 100001\\
& 1      & + 1 = & 2\\
}`

Answer (score 3):

Try the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\setlength{\arraycolsep}{1pt}

% only for demonstrate page layout and show some dummy text
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%%%%
        \begin{document}
\lipsum[2]
\begin{flalign*}
\begin{array}{@{}lll}
100000 & + 1 & = 100001 \\
1      & + 1 & = 2 
\end{array} &&   
\end{flalign*}
\lipsum[2]
        \end{document}
```

[image]

However, if all equations should be lef aligned, thab it is sensible to use option from amsmath, like

```
\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}
```

which do this for all equations in document.